# Oxygen dissociation curve and temperature

Tags: respiration, breathing

Say, we have a container with a mixture of gases. The concentration of oxygen is $C_{oxy}$ and its partial pressure is $P_{oxy}$. We then introduce a sample of hemoglobin (deoxygenated) in that container. A certain fraction of the sample gets saturated  with oxygen. Afterwards, we increase the temperature of the gas in the container keeping everything else constant. $P_{oxy}$
obviously increases. Does this mean that the percentage of saturated hemoglobin increases as well with the increase in $P_{oxy}$, according to the ODC curve?

Or, will the oxygen saturation decrease, as at higher temperatures the $Hb-O_{2}$ bond starts getting denatured? If the latter is the case, does this imply the ODC curve is temperature specific? And if that is the case, wouldn't the ODC curve (partial pressure Vs saturation curve for a specific temperature) be a mere concentration vs saturation curve for a specific temperature?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE... can you give some evidence of effort on your part to try and figure this out? where have you looked for an answer?

Comment: Added my idea. Can you help? @VanceLAlbaugh

Comment: ..saturation actually depends on the concentration... If thats the case then why do we experience mountain sickness?